# Why does PostgreSQL convert a timestamp that has an UTC offset to UTC format, although the column type is "timestamp with time zone"?

Tags: postgresql, docker, macos

I use PostgreSQL in Docker, and I also have installed PostgreSQL on my Mac. In Docker it converts timestamp with timezone to UTC, but in the installed PostgreSQL it saves the time zone offset.

I enter the value `2021-03-25 01:08:25+02`, but it converts to UTC:

| startDate |
| --- |
| 2021-03-24 23:08:25+00 |

I enter the same value (`2021-03-25 01:08:25+02`) into the program:

| t2 |
| --- |
| 2021-03-25 01:08:25+02 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `timezone` parameter is different in both session. PostgreSQL always displays `timestamp with time zone` according to the current setting of `timezone`, so you should set that correctly for each database session.